# Abuse, Postmaster, Webmaster addresses required for each subdomain?

Tags: domains, email, spam-prevention

I have a base domain that has the `abuse@domain.com`, `webmaster@domain.com`, `postmaster@domain.com`, etc. However, I want to set up a new subdomain from the base domain. Does this new subdomain require separate addresses (ex: `abuse@sub.domain.com`)?

Comment: No.  (  I would argue you don't even need the specified addresses for the root domain for it to operate acceptably on the Internet )

Comment: Ok thanks @davidgo!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the sub-domains are just DNS records on the primary domain.

For example:

- `www.example.com`
- `beta.example.com`
- `email.example.com`
- `store.beta.example.com`

`www`, `beta`, `email` and `store.beta` are all sub-domains on `example.com`, so any details for that domain will apply.

Depending on the registrar you may be required to specify and list a contact email for the domain but this doesn't have to be on the domain itself.

If you wish to purchase an SSL cert for the domain there is often a requirement to be able to receive emails on a known name (typically admin, webmaster or postmaster), but these are for the primary domain, not for the sub-domains.

Answer (score -1):

It is better to do it this way, that each subdomain has its own emails.

Email service providers control their sending domains and associate sender reputation with their domain. If you don't distinguish between them, problems on a subdomain can affect the sender reputation of the entire domain.

In addition, messages for a subdomain may be masked when sent to the domain and the subdomain to which they refer cannot be detected.